# Is it possible to successfully merge transitive assembly references with ILMerge?

Tags: .net, antlr, ilmerge, stringtemplate

I'm trying to use ILMerge to internalize some transitively referenced assemblies into an assembly I'm referencing to eliminate conflicts with those transitive dependencies elsehwere in my project.

In particular, I'm referencing *Antlr3.StringTemplate* (hereafter referred to as AS, available here: http://www.stringtemplate.org/download.html).  It references *Antlr3.Runtime.Debug* (ARD) and *Antlr3.Runtime* (AR).  ARD itself also references AR.  In ASCII-art, that's:

```
AS ---> ARD
\        |
 \       v
  \---> AR
```

Because another assembly I'm using, NHibernate 2.1, depends on different, incompatible version of AR, I wanted to use ILMerge to merge and internalize AR into AS.  In theory, I think this should work; however, I'm having trouble executing the theory.

No matter what permutations and options I try, I end up with an error of the following form:

> ILMerge.Merge: The assembly
>   'Antlr3.Runtime.Debug' was not merged
>   in correctly. It is still listed as an
>   external reference in the target
>   assembly.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish with ILMerge even possible?

Comment: What evidence do you have that suggests that the error message you receive is due to the transitive assembly references? From the information you provided, it sounds like it's just a random bug in ILMerge. It may be the same bug as this one: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=320999&wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 5):

When you run ILMerge from the command line (or within an MSBuild task), of all the assembly files you list out to be merged, it is the *first* one that is considered the *primary assembly* when the merging begins. If you haven't already, ensure that the AS assembly filename is listed first in you list of merging assemblies.

Answer (score 5):

The most recent version of ILMerge has a `/closed` option which works on the transitive closure of the merged assemblies. It solves this exact problem (see sections `2.6 Closed` and `4.1 Input assembly not merged in correctly` in the ILMerge.doc user manual).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to ILMerge all of my Nhibernate related .dlls into one to get it to sit nicely with StringTemplate. Probably not the answer you were hoping for but it works.